# How to get username in Windows domain from service using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows

I need get the name of the domain user in Windows.

Here are the ways by which I tried to get a name, but they all return the domain name:

**1.**

```
...
ENV['username'] # or ENV['USERNAME'] or ENV['userid']
...
```

**2.**

```
...
require 'etc'
puts Etc.getlogin
...
```

**3.**

```
...
require 'dl/win32'

def get_user_name
  api = Win32API.new(
    'advapi32.dll',
    'GetUserName',
    'PP',
    'i'
  )

  buf = "\0" * 512
  len = [512].pack('L')
  api.call(buf,len)

  buf[0..(len.unpack('L')[0])]
end
...
```

**4.**

This way return string `"system"`:

```
...
require 'win32ole'
network=WIN32OLE.new("Wscript.Network")
puts network.username
...
```

How can I get username or pair domain\username?

Comment: Does using `WhoAmI` or `WhoAmI /UPN` or `WhoAmI /FQDN` or `WhoAmI /user` help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you run system commands and store them in a variable.

```
u = `WhoAmI /user`
```

Now `u` has the user information for your processing, isnt?